# NSManagedObjectContext doesn't save a column alone?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

I am trying to save some data to my core data table. I am experiencing a trouble that only one column value is not saved with the value passed.

I have almost wasted a day to figure this out.

```
[contactObj setLastName:@"Hey"]; NSLog(@"LAST NAME CHECk : %@ %@",
[contactDict objectForKey:@"LastName"], contactObj.lastName); // Here contactObj.lastName
its printing.But not saved
```

Please suggest /help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you call the "save" method of your NSManagedObjectContext instance? It has a cache mechanism and may cause your problem. Try this:

```
NSError *err = nil;
[INSTANCE_NAME_OF_YOUR_NSManagedObjectContext save:&err];
```

Comment: Yes I called. All the columns are saved except this.

Comment: @EaswaramoorthyK this is weird. I would then go check if there's any problem with the setter and getter of "last name" as well as the settings in the .xcdatamodeld file. I also suggest you add the information of what you have tried to solve the problem to your question.